# How to export an animated texture from Blender to three.js?

Tags: three.js, textures, blender

I have an animated fire "burning" on a round plane on Blender. It's very similar to the one found in this [tutorial link.](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-fire-cycles/) I want the render the model on three.js.
I tried the Blend4Web HTML format and only the texture of the fire didn't appear.
I also, exported it to .json and collada with the three.js exporter. No results.

Do I use UV mapping?

Comment: Can you link your `.blend` file so we can look at the problem a bit more closely?

Comment: How can I link the .blend file?

Comment: Dropbox or a similar service might help. Just share it and post link here.